# Java Scanner class, nothing displayed

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, intellij-15

I'm new in Java, and i can't figure out why this code doesn't work (no error but nothing displays on the console).

Thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String str2 = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please write something : ");

    System.out.println("You wrote : "+str2);

}

}
```

Comment: `nextLine()` blocks until a new line is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must enter something and hit enter in order to see any output.

You might want to print the prompt before calling `nextLine` :

```
System.out.println("Please write something : ");
String str2 = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("You wrote : "+str2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because this piece of code **String str2 = sc.nextLine();** expecting the input by main thread. Until you enter something into the console, control won't go to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

This is, how you want to implement it:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please write something : ");

        String str2 = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("You wrote : " + str2);
    }
}
```